# PHP : Get a number between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
a:3:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:3;i:2;i:4;}
```

I want to get number between "a:" and ":{" that is "3".
I try to user substr and strpos but no success.
I'm newbie in regex , write this :

```
preg_match('/a:(.+?):{/', $v);
```

But its return me 1.
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: This looks like a serialized PHP array (with a wrong number of elements …?). Why not deserialize it and use `count()` on the actual array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `a:` is always at the beginning of the string, the easiest way is:

```
$array = explode( ':', $string, 3 );
$number = $array[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) returns the number of matches, in your case 1 match.

To get the matches themselves, use the third parameter:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match(/'a:(\d+?):{/', $v, $matches);
```

That said, I think the string looks like a serialized array which you could deserialize with [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) and then use `count` on the actual array (i.e. `$a = count(unserialize($v));`). Be careful with userprovided serialized strings though …

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sscanf`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/sscanf) to obtain the number from the string:

```
# Input:
$str = 'a:3:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:3;i:2;i:4;}';

# Code:
sscanf($str, 'a:%d:', $number);

# Output:
echo $number; # 3
```

This is often more simple than using `preg_match` when you'd like to obtain a specific value from a string that follows a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match()` returns the number of times it finds a match, that's why. you need to add a third param. `$matches` in which it will store the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You were not too far away with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$pos_start = strpos($str,'a:')+2;
$pos_end = strpos($str,':{')-2;
$result = substr($str,$pos_start,$pos_end);
```

preg_match only checks for appearance, it doesn't return any string.

Comment: True, I forgot to make the position of $pos_start +2 (for the 2 characters of `a:` Now it should be ok.

Comment: Not my day, so sorry! Edited it now, tested, works - even with more than one number. Reason for -2 at the end of $pos_end is that you need to decrease the length of 2, when you increased the $pos_start of 2.